# Importing a listener defined string variable into another package

Tags: java, swing, listener

I have a package that contains my input form. The idea was that the input form would record the answers and store them as variables, I would then import the variables into a different package where an algorithm would perform calculations.

I've been reading up on importing variables, however I'm not sure how to implement the code correctly into my existing code.

```
package inputform;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Traitform extends JFrame {

        JPanel set1 = new JPanel();
        //add labels
        JRadioButton momEye1 = new JRadioButton("brown");
        JRadioButton momEye2 = new JRadioButton("blue");

        JPanel set2 = new JPanel();
        JRadioButton momHair1 = new JRadioButton("brown");
        JRadioButton momHair2 = new JRadioButton("blonde");

        JPanel set3 = new JPanel();
        JRadioButton dadEye1 = new JRadioButton("brown");
        JRadioButton dadEye2 = new JRadioButton("blue");

        JPanel set4 = new JPanel();
        JRadioButton dadHair1 = new JRadioButton("brown");
        JRadioButton dadHair2 = new JRadioButton("blonde");

        public Traitform () {
            super("Parent Trait Form");
            setSize(1000, 1000);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0,1);
            setLayout(layout);

            ButtonGroup group1 =  new ButtonGroup();
            group1.add(momEye1);
            group1.add(momEye2);

            class geneActionListener implements ActionListener {
            @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ex) {
                    String choice = group1.getSelection().getActionCommand();
                    System.out.println("trait selected" + choice);
            } 
        }
            ActionListener al = new geneActionListener();
            momEye1.addActionListener(al);
            momEye2.addActionListener(al);
            momEye1.setActionCommand("brown");
            momEye2.setActionCommand("blue");

            ButtonGroup group2 =  new ButtonGroup();
            group2.add(momHair1);
            group2.add(momHair2);

            ButtonGroup group3 =  new ButtonGroup();
            group3.add(dadEye1);
            group3.add(dadEye2);

            ButtonGroup group4 =  new ButtonGroup();
            group4.add(dadHair1);
            group4.add(dadHair2);

            set1.add(momEye1);
            set1.add(momEye2);

            set2.add(momHair1);
            set2.add(momHair2);

            set3.add(dadEye1);
            set3.add(dadEye2);

            set4.add(dadHair1);
            set4.add(dadHair2);

            add(set1);
            add(set2);
            add(set3);
            add(set4);

            setVisible(true);

            group1.getSelection().getActionCommand();         
        }

    private static void setLookAndFeel() {
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                } catch (Exception exc){

            }
    }
        public static void main(String[] arguments){
            Traitform.setLookAndFeel();
            Traitform frame = new Traitform();
        }       
}
```

The class I'm importing into:

```
package parents;

import inputform.Traitform;

public class parents {

    public static void main(String[] arguments){

        // algorithm goes here to predict the odds of the child having blue or brown eyes
        // and blonde or brown hair

    }    
}
```

I thought I could just import the variable choice using `import`  but the variable "choice" is never recognized in the parents class, meaning it doesn't get imported. I'm not sure how to properly import the variable since online examples assume its the only task at hand.

Comment: *algorithm goes here* - The algorithm goes in the class that contains the data. For example you have a button that you click that analyses all the data from the class. The main() method is just used to create and display the form. All related processing is contained in the form or in child classes of the form. And in your last question (https://coderanch.com/t/713253/java/trouble-actionlistener-work-checkboxes) you were given a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Radio Buttons` that shows you how to define variables that can be used by any method of your form class.

Comment: (1-) You have also been told you should NOT be defining a class in the middle of a constructor/method. You can define anonymous inner classes that way.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. I designed this program as an attempt to use everything I had learned so far, I guess I'll just need to do that with a different program. I'll try to finish this one up the proper way and move on to a new project. Thanks for all the help camickr.

Comment: The code posted is way too long to demonstrate the issue. Please post [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To gain flexibility and better decoupling of gui and logic, consider implementing [mvc pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern)
Simply put, using this pattern you have a "dumb" view, which does just that.
You have a model class, which is responsible for holding the information and logic used by the view.
You have a controller which controls: "wires" the view and the model. 
The following is [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) version of your code <sup>(1)</sup>, aimed to show a possible solution.
For convinience the entire code can be copy-pasted into one file  (`Traitform.java`):

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

//better practice is to have a `JFrame instance rather than extending it 
public class Traitform extends JFrame { 

    public Traitform (Model model) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0,1);
        setLayout(layout);

        JRadioButton momEye1 = new JRadioButton("brown");
        JRadioButton momEye2 = new JRadioButton("blue");
        ButtonGroup group1 =  new ButtonGroup();
        group1.add(momEye1);
        group1.add(momEye2);

        class geneActionListener implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ex) {
                String choice = group1.getSelection().getActionCommand();
                model.setChoice(choice);
            }
        }

        ActionListener al = new geneActionListener();
        momEye1.addActionListener(al);
        momEye2.addActionListener(al);
        momEye1.setActionCommand("brown");
        momEye2.setActionCommand("blue");

        JPanel set1 = new JPanel();
        set1.add(momEye1);
        set1.add(momEye2);

        add(set1);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        new Controller();
    }
}

//controls and "wires" view and model
class Controller{
    Model model = new Model();   //construct a model
    Traitform view = new Traitform(model);   //construct a view 
}

//holds information and logic used by view
class Model{
    private String choice;

    String getChoice() {
        return choice;
    }

    void setChoice(String choice) {
        this.choice = choice;
        System.out.println("choice in model changed to "+ choice);
    }
}
```

By using this simple structure the view (represented by `Traitform` in this example) the model is updated by the view.
Controller holds an instance of `Model` so it can access the information in it by `model.getChoice()`.
The controller can also path a reference of `model` to any other class that may need it or implement a listener that listens to changes in `Model`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Posting mcve in questions makes help easier and quicker.